# How to tell if a Google oAuth2 API user is logged into my C# app

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm working on a c# project that uses Google OAuth2 API for log-in and log-out operations. If a user logs in and then closes the app without logging out they stay logged in.
I'm wondering if anyone knows how I can tell when the user boots up my app if they are currently logged into a google account or if they have not yet
(since part of my app needs the API and the other part doesn't require it.)

This is how I log them out of my app:

```
        UserCredential credential;
        credential = GetCredentials();
        Debug.WriteLine(credential);
        await credential.RevokeTokenAsync(new CancellationToken());
```

GetCredentials() is:

```
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        }
        return credential;
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the code that you have tried so that we may better assist you.

Comment: To be honest I don’t even know where to start - I am just using the Google .NET OAuth api and was seeing how to check if a user is logged in

Comment: I would start by checking out the following resource https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ .  Look into `ClaimsPrincipal` object, and anything that says `External` authentication.

Comment: Here's another one that might come in handy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] You cant log a user out of their google account. You need to log the user out of your app.  How that is done depends upon your app and your code.  Without seeing it its hard for us to help you.

Comment: If you are using the google .net client library as you have tagged your question then you should consult [web-applications-asp.net-core-3](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-core-3)